# How does babel implement Set / Map polyfills

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

My question is related to computational complexity of Set / Map, Weak Set / Weak Map polyfills by Babel? Afaik there are no ES5 language features allowing to implement Set / Map directly, and so it might happen that Set / Map might use Array structure under the hood to implement lookup by object reference which would yield to O(N) lookup performance. And so the question is:

What is the computational complexity of Set / Map lookup operations?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [tag:babel]: *"Python internationalization library with an emphasis on web-based applications. For questions about the JavaScript library, please use [tag:babeljs]."* (=> please read tag descriptions)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Babel uses core-js for its polyfill, from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-collections):

> core-js uses native collections in most case, just fixes methods /
> constructor, if it's required, and in old environment uses fast
> polyfill **(O(1) lookup)**.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

And if you're interested in the exact lookup, it's in [this file](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/v2.0.3/modules/_meta.js#LC18). It's not backed by an array.